# mysql query - 3 tables - can't get it right

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to do a PDO statement that cross-references 3 tables and it seems i'm stuck.

It basically needs 4 records from 2 tables (**myl_contacts** and **mya_users**) and they don't need to be listed in **myl_blocked_contacts**.

In myl_blocked_contacts are the rows with id, and contact_type ('a', 'l', 'x', etc) which are blocked, and I need to select from myl_contacts users that I have and are NOT blocked (hence are not in myl_blocked contacts).

Here's the piece of PDO::mysql query that I've done so far. I don't know where to go from here, I am trying a lot of things off the net, but I seem to go in the wrong direction somehow. Thanks!

```
$query = "SELECT myl_contacts.contact_id, mya_users.name, mya_users.city, mya_users.ext 
      from myl_contacts, mya_users, 
          LEFT JOIN myl_blocked_contacts 
      WHERE myl_contacts.contact_type='a' 
        AND myl_contacts.label_id=:id 
        AND (myl_blocked_contacts.contact_type!='a' 
         AND myl_blocked_contacts.contact_id!=mya_users.id)
     ";
                                            $result = $db->prepare($query);
                                            $result->bindValue(':id', $_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                                            $result->execute();
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having exactly?

Comment: *side note - myl_contacts and myl_blocked contacts have 4 columns both, are identical, but the difference is that in 1st table there are normal contacts, and in 2nd there are blocked contacts. THere can be a contact in 1st table but if it's in the 2nd too then it's blocked (so ppl can not send them mail, that's what blocked means actually for me).

Comment: If you want help with the query you are going to have to post relevant table information, and the desired results. Also, edit your question to respond to comments.

Comment: the problem is that it lists no answers...no rows

Comment: Your join is missing an 'on' clause. You should inspect `$db->errorInfo()` if you are not getting error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get your problem right.
I don't understand why you use the `LEFT JOIN`.
Isn't there a `ON` part needed? (like `... t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = t2.t1ID ...`)

What if you just write:

```
SELECT 
    myl_contacts.contact_id, 
    mya_users.name, 
    mya_users.city, 
    mya_users.ext 
FROM 
    myl_contacts, 
    mya_users, 
WHERE 
    myl_contacts.contact_type='a' 
    AND myl_contacts.label_id=:id 
    AND mya_users.id NOT IN
        SELECT 
            contact_id
        FROM
            myl_blocked_contacts
```

I also don't quite understand why you `SELECT` rows from different tables which are not related. This might make sense, but does not necessarily. If there's some connection between these tables, you might want to add an `INNER JOIN`...

Comment: hey...your post is similar to deizel....it will work, i'm tweaking...thanks for posting

Comment: Yes, you're right. But this seems to be the most reasonable way. Pls. let me comment on your `myl_contacts` and `mya_users` tables. Is there some reference in `mya_users` to a column in `myl_contacts` (i.e. some column in `mya_users` which holds the contact ID from `myl_contacts`)?

Comment: yes, i can use both myl_contacts.contact_id or mya_users.id ...they are different tables and i need to hold the id in both...the id is the artist's id and contact_id represents the id of artist or label, diff stuff....i need them where they are

Comment: but...for some reason,...both pieces of code double the result i'm getting (double lines with same stuff on it) as a result. would you happen to know why ?

Comment: ok, try the following: `SELECT 
    myl_contacts.contact_id, 
    mya_users.name, 
    mya_users.city, 
    mya_users.ext 
FROM 
    myl_contacts INNER JOIN
    mya_users ON myl_contacts.contact_id = mya_users.id WHERE ...`

Comment: weee....it works!!! now no more double values and random stuff....how does the INNER JOIN do the miracle work ? can you explain a bit what it does on this last line you helped me with or a great resource for it ? thank man, really appreciate it. you have 2 good beers on me :)

Comment: sure. Have a look at your query. You want to read values from your `myl_contacts` table with a specific `contact_type` and a specific `label_id`. That's exactly what's being returned. You also read values from the second table. Both results are returned. The database does not know that the two tables are somehow connected to each other. What you ACTUALLY want to do is: return all the people who have the contact type 'a' AND whose label_id is :id AND whose ids **in the users table** are not listed in the blocked list. BUT: Which id in the users table belongs to which entry in the contacts table

Comment: And here's where the INNER JOIN helps: The INNER JOIN joins the contacts table and the users table in a way that the resulting (joined) table (which is kept only in memory for the time of your query) has all the entries of the contacts table PLUS all the CORRESPONDING entries of the users table. Now there's a connection between these two tables and you can use columns from both tables in your WHERE clause (as both tables are joined into one big table by resolving the relations between both tables (i. e. the IDs)

Comment: It's very difficult to explain without any graphics or text formatting... But you should DEFINITELY know about `INNER JOIN`s (as well as `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`s, `FULL OUTER JOIN`s, and `CROSS JOIN`s. It's quite easy once you understood it... You might want to read this article [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_join#Inner_join), or this [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17719/discussion-between-toms-and-adrian-tanase)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT IN` with a sub-query selecting the IDs you're not interested in:

```
select myl_contacts.contact_id, mya_users.name, mya_users.city, mya_users.ext 
from myl_contacts
left join mya_users on myl_contacts.contact_id = mya_users.contact_id -- (?)
where
  myl_contacts.contact_type = 'a' and
  myl_contacts.label_id = :id and
  myl_contacts.contact_id not in
  (
    select myl_blocked_contacts.contact_id
    from myl_blocked_contacts
    where myl_blocked_contacts.contact_type <> 'a'
  )
```

Comment: it displays 2 rows twice, so it doubles the 2 output rows, and also does not keep track 1 row that I block in myl_blocked_contacts

Comment: i'm tweaking your post, deizel and will keep you posted once i've done it. thanks a lot for your piece of code